# Oracle After update trigger for bulk update

Tags: oracle

Is there any way to program an oracle after update trigger to insert only the most recent record in a history table, when a bulk update is performed.

Comment: What do you mean by only the most recent - the new state of all the updated rows? What have you tried and what isn't working as you want it to?

Comment: Lets suppose a bulk update was performed, updating a record like for 10 times. If I program a trigger with "FOR EACH ROW" then 10 new records will be created for each update against same ID. I do not want that, I want to know is there any way by which I can only get the last record (in this case the 10th record) which will have all the updated values for previously updated 9 records.

Comment: So far I have designed a temporary table in which all the updated records are inserted. Afterwards, I find duplicates using ids  in that table, order by records according to their creation date (in a descending fashion) and then update my history table. Another more reliable approach I am following is by using query select *              FROM 
( SELECT  
    e.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by root_id order by history_creation_dte DESC) r--, status ASC) r
FROM  
    APP_TRANSACTION_R_TEMP  e
)        WHERE r=1;

Comment: But this approach is not the most reliable one. I am looking for a more efficient and more reliable approach.

Comment: Please add significant information, especially code, as an edit to the question rather than as a comment. Why is your update touching the same row 10 times? What mechanism are you using for the updates? If the 10th update includes all the changes from the previous 9 anyway why not just execute that one?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you leave out the `for each row` clause. Than you can achieve a statement trigger, that only fires after the commit of one transaction. Software could be something like this:

```
create or replace trigger ai_test
after insert on orders

declare

my_test_row orders%rowtype;

begin


select o.*
into my_test_row
from orders o
where o.order_date = (select max(order_date) -- must be the identifying attribute 
                      from orders);


insert into orders_his (id, cust_id, prod_id, order_date) 
values  
( my_test_row.id
, my_test_row.cust_id
, my_test_row.prod_id
, my_test_row.order_date);             


end;
```